# Django admin login for particular url

Tags: django

i'm using Django admin for admin operation on Movies model like :

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
 url(r'^admin/movies/', include('movies.adminurls')),
```

when request comes like `**http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/**` it shows admin-login page
there is Movie model which i can mange from there.

since Movies model have 15 fields , it would be tedious task to fill in data for 100 movies from admin site.

For that i have created a view **add_movie** in which i'll populate Movies table through json data.
**movies.adminurls**

```
 url(r'^add/', 'add_movie' , name="admin_add_movie"),
```

for **add_movie** admin must be logged in. request is like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/movies/add/
```

if superuser is not logged in then it should display admin-login form. and  when superuser is successfully logged in then it should redirect to **add_movie** view

So

is it  possible to show admin-login for that url?

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect to the admin login form if user is not superuser:

```
def add_movie(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not (request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_superuser):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_URL+'?next=/admin/movies/add/')
    do_your_stuff(...)
```

If it is an API, you may want to raise `PermissionDenied` instead.

Comment: with a little change it worked    
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')

Answer (score 0):

After facing your problem I finally find a django decorator with check whether user is admin or logged in and shows your view else returns login form and after login redirects to your page.

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
@staff_member_required
def media_browser(request):
    return HttpResponse("You logged in")
```