# Django strange admin login redirect

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-admin, django-views

I faced strange thing in django admin. I designed a file browser for my admin. In my file browser view I check if user is admin then render my file browser template else redirect to admin login. Until now evrything works perfect but when I input username,password and press Login button, the Login button redirects me to the `mysite.com/admin/admin/` page which is not exist. This is part of my file browser view and urls code.

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', home),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/file_browser$', file_browser),)

# views.py
def file_browser(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return render(request, 'admin/browser.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('admin/')
```

And I've read similar question in [Django admin login for particular url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447984/django-admin-login-for-particular-url) and it works fine until I press login button then django raises error that settings.LOGIN_URL is not exist or sometimes 404 error. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

After searching through django admin files I finally found a decorator for this:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
@staff_member_required
def media_browser(request):
    return HttpResponse("You logged in")
```

Hope for those who have this problem it works.